# How to create a copy and then update 1 tag in xslt?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am new to XSLT. I need to render all the content inside every toaEntry block. And if inside toaEntry, charfill tag is present; i have to update it by adding numchar='2'. Also toaEntry should be converted to <auth.ref>

Following is my input:

```
<auth>
    <toaEntry>W. Prosser,
         <ital>xxx</ital> (4th ed. 1971) § 131 at 980-981,
         <ital>yyy</ital> (5th ed. 1984) § 131 at 1053-1054
         <charfill>․</charfill> 146
    </toaEntry>
    <toaEntry>
         <reference>
              <ital>mmm</ital> § 161
         </reference> comment b (1965)
         <ital>aaa</ital> 751 (1961)
         <charfill>-</charfill> 92,11,22
    </toaEntry>
</auth>
```

And i need an output like this:

```
<sample>
    <auth.ref>W. Prosser,
    <ital>xxx</ital> (4th ed. 1971) § 131 at 980-981,
    <ital>yyy</ital> (5th ed. 1984) § 131 at 1053-1054
    <charfill numchar='2'>․</charfill> 146
    </auth.ref>
    <auth.ref>
         <reference>
              <ital>mmm</ital> § 161
         </reference> comment b (1965)
         <ital>aaa</ital> 751 (1961)
         <charfill numchar='2'>-</charfill> 92,11,22
    </auth.ref>
</sample>
```

Comment: Well, try any XSLT tutorial introducing the identity transformation and template matching and you can give it a try. Just telling us you are new doesn't prevent you from reading existing tutorials/books/introductions before asking. Show where and how you fail if you really can't work it out.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen, I tried identity transformation, I am able to render all the content inside <toaEntry> using <xsl:copy-of> but then how will i update the charfill tag? I am stucked here.
`
<xsl:template match="auth/toaEntry">
     <xsl:element name="auth.reference">
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
     </xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>
`
Above xsl will give output like:
`
<auth.ref>W. Prosser,
    <ital>xxx</ital> (4th ed. 1971) § 131 at 980-981,
    <ital>yyy</ital> (5th ed. 1984) § 131 at 1053-1054
    <charfill >․</charfill> 146
    </auth.ref>
`

Comment: As the one asking the question,  put any code into code samples in your question, not inside a comment. If you want to use the identity transformation as the base template and add further transformation tasks, write one template matching each type of node you want to transform and keep the processing chain alive by using `<xsl:apply-templates/>` or `,<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>`, don't revert to `copy-of`. So if you use `<xsl:template match="auth/toaEntry"><auth.reference><xsl:apply-templates/></auth.reference></xsl:template>`, you only need a third template `match="charfill"`.